# PHP - Ping exec on Linux hangs script

Tags: php, linux, exec, ping, freeze

I have a simple PHP script setup to check the status of my servers. It uses a standard ping command, run via exec().

- On Windows, the script works fine both when a server is online and
  when down.
- On Linux, the script works when the server is online, but hangs when
  the server is down. Timeout seems to have no effect on the latter.

Pinging with the same command via console works fine and times out correctly.

---

What's the cause, and how would this be fixed?

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
  $exec_string = 'ping -n 1 -i 255 -w 2 ' . $host;
} else {
  $exec_string = 'ping -n -c 1 -t 255 -w 2 ' . $host;
}
exec($exec_string, $output, $return);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why, but switching from suPHP to fastCGI (both with suEXEC enabled) seemed to resolve the issue and the ping properly times out as expected.

If anyone has an explanation for this, I would love to know, in either comment or answer format.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid pinging directly using an `exec()`. I use this script, [found here](http://www.thecave.info/php-ping-script-to-check-remote-server-or-website/), you can also setup port and timeout:

```
function ping($host, $port = 80, $timeout = 6) {
    $fsock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!$fsock) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$host = 'www.example.com';

if(ping($host)) {
    echo "HOST UP";
} else {
    echo "HOST DOWN";
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is a proper solution, especially because this works if system function calls aren't available. But you didn't explain _why_ you would avoid ping using an exec?

Comment: fsockopen is already being used as a backup solution, so it wasn't included in the question.

Comment: I tend to avoid `exec()` because they are often disabled for security reasons.

Comment: Link is obsolete.